# Expresso Store: Realex Payments

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

i am very interested in new 2.0 version and see as with 1.0 there is no option for Realex Payments (irish payments handler) support. i know this is a niche market but is the only thing stopping me using this ecommerce in our projects.

Is there any plans to expand the payment providers ?

http://www.realexpayments.com/developers

Comment: I presume this is in reference to Exp:resso Store v2? I've edited your title to reflect along with adding the  appropriate tag. Feel free to edit if that's incorrect.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get a more official response, but even if an official gateway is not released, it's not incredibly difficult to write your own, or you can sponsor the development of the gateway with Exp:resso.

Comment: This is a feature request for Exp:resso store, not a real EE question

Answer (score 2):

If this is in reference to Store v2 then the good news is that support for the Realex payment gateway is intended to be rolled out in the next month or two. Keep an eye on the [release notes](https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html) for confirmation of when it's been added to the available gateways.