# Is there a Realex Payments module for Expresso Store 2?

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

As per this post (from October last)

[https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14325/expresso-store-realex-payments#*=*](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14325/expresso-store-realex-payments#_=_)

Is there any support for Realex Payments provider? I have commissioned the Realex payment module for the previous version of Store, but we have moved on the upgrades and now need to offer the same thing for what is a much better store version.

Comment: Any update on this? **Omnipay** now includes Realex Payments in their listings: https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we've not had time to implement it for Store v2 as of yet. There are a few complications with that gateway that we found out about when building integration with Store v1. For that reason it took a bit more work than the others and as of yet we haven't had a chance to build a gateway extension for it.

A few people have mentioned they'd be interesting in sponsoring development of it but as of yet we've not had any follow-ups. The option is always there for split cost sponsorship. If enough people are interested then it wouldn't work out that much at all when divided.

Comment: well we sponsored the previous implementation with the previous version of store, so I think we might defer on this one.